Why is IPv4 not working on Ubuntu 22.04 with new router/network
I am trying to connect to a new router using my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop.
It connects just fine, however I am having troubles getting IPV4 to work.
If I go to https://www.whatismyip.com/, most of the time I get a result like:

My Public IPv4: "Not Detected"
My Public IPv6: "my IPV6 address"

Sometimes I get an IP showing, but that usually only lasts a couple of seconds after which it fails again.
I tested IPv4 and IPv6 separately, by doing
ping4 www.google.com
ping6 www.google.com

ping4 results in 100% packet loss, ping6 works fine.
My phone does not have this issue, and I am connected over wifi.
Surely you will need more specific details regarding my network, but I am not sure what to give. Let me know which command outputs you need that can be of help.
